# radiusnetworks ibeacon service background trigger at android

Tags: android, ibeacon-android

i m using radiusnetworks's ibeacon service. but its always scanning next munites first seconds. how can i trigger it every 10 second?

trigger at beaconserviceutility :

```
private void startBackgroundScan() {

alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(), 6000, pintent);

    context.startService(iService);
}
```

notification at beaconservice:

```
private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

    Intent launchIntent = new Intent(context, MonitoringActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    ((NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(
            0,
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setTicker(message)
                    .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name)).setContentText(message)
                    .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, launchIntent, 0)).setAutoCancel(true)
                    .build());

}
```

i trigged it every 6 second, but it always running at next munite. example, it working at 13:00:00 and next scanning at 13:01:00.

how can change it and trigger it every 10second? thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/), you don't need to set up any alarms or timers to make it periodically scan for beacons in the background.  It does so automatically, and you can configure the frequency.

You can see an example of how to set this up in the "Starting an App in the Background" section here:  http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

In order to customize it to do a two second scan for beacons every 10 seconds while in the background, you modify the above referenced sample code to add the bottom three lines below:

```
    Region region = new Region("com.example.myapp.boostrapRegion", null, null, null);
    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
    BeaconManager manager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    manager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(10000l); // 10 seconds
    manager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(2000l); // 2 seconds
```

You can read more about how to customize scan intervals here:  http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/battery_manager.html

Comment: hi, my beaconmanager isn't has setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod and setBackgroundScanPeriod methods.

Comment: Exactly what library and version are you using?

Comment: i m late..  radiusnetworks. i used this, https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/android-ibeacon-service

Comment: That library has been deprecated in favor of the Android Beacon Library linked above.  You can see migration instructions here: https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/api-migrate.md